# How Do I Set the WordPress Page Title Dynamically for Template where page Data received from cURL?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using template for certain post types and within the page I have cURL calls in order to receive data from the API and use for page content (title, content, image urls etc).
Is it possible to use received cURL data and change page title directly inside the template php file? I got title from API inside the variable $title:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Page */ ?>
<?php
 global $wp_query;

 $page_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['page_id'];
 $pageData = (!empty($page_slug)) ? get_page_data($page_slug) : null;

 // get_page_data(); method with cURL logic that returns array

 if($pageData === null) {
  wp_redirect(WEBSITE_ROOT.'404/', 302);
 }

 $title = $pageData['title']; // Use this for page title (<title></title>)

 get_header();
?>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for a line saying `the_title();`, there you should be able to replace it with ur custom name.